# Abbreviated month or day of the week with a DOT (".") at the end of the string

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, utf-8, locale

I need to change with python a lot of **strings** with a **Spanish date format** (DDMMMYYYY, MMM abbreviated month in Spanish) in a other datetime format but I'm having problems because my locale Spanish settings has a "." (a **dot**) at the end of the string when it change this format in a abbreviated month format.

By default, python take the English version of the language but I can change the language with the **locale** library.
When I select **'esp'** or **'es_ES.utf8'** the dot at the end of the abbreviated month appears.

Does it depend on the regional settings of my Windows 10? (I check it and all seems OK) Does it depend on the LOCALE library settings?
The same code in UBUNTU runs OK (without the point)

How can I solve this problem?

I don't want to transform all the strings like that..

```
str_date = str_date[:5] + "." + str_date[5:]
```

Thanks a lot!!

**Example** (previously I change the language with locale):

```
>>> datetime.strptime('2021-01-18', '%Y-%m-%d').strftime('%b')
'ene.'
>>> print(datetime.strptime('18ene2021', '%d%b%Y'))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\galonsoi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\_strptime.py", line 565, in _strptime_datetime
    tt, fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
  File "C:\Users\galonsoi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\_strptime.py", line 362, in _strptime
    (data_string, format))
ValueError: time data '18ene2021' does not match format '%d%b%Y'
>>> print(datetime.strptime('18ene.2021', '%d%b%Y'))
2021-01-18 00:00:00                                       ----> THIS IS OK BECAUSE I WRITE THE DOT AT THE END OF THE ABBREVIATED MONTH
```

**Complete sequence of the Example**

```
>>> import locale
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>>
>>> locale.getlocale()
(None, None)
>>> print (datetime.strptime('2021-01-18', '%Y-%m-%d').strftime('%b'))
Jan
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')
`Spanish_Spain.1252`
>>> locale.getlocale()
(`es_ES`, `cp1252`)
#INCORRECT FORMAT, ADD A "." AT THE END
>>> print (datetime.strptime('2021-01-18', '%Y-%m-%d').strftime('%b'))
ene.
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'es_ES.UTF-8')
`es_ES.UTF-8`
#FORMATO INCORRECTO, AÑADE UN "." a may
>>> print (datetime.strptime('2021-01-18', '%Y-%m-%d').strftime('%b'))
ene.
>>> print(datetime.strptime('18ene2021', '%d%b%Y'))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\galonsoi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\_strptime.py", line 565, in _strptime_datetime
    tt, fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
  File "C:\Users\galonsoi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\_strptime.py", line 362, in _strptime
    (data_string, format))
ValueError: time data '18ene2021' does not match format '%d%b%Y'
>>> print(datetime.strptime('18ene.2021', '%d%b%Y'))
2021-01-18 00:00:00                                       ----> THIS IS OK BECAUSE I WROTE THE DOT AT THE END OF THE ABBREVIATED MONTH
```

Comment: to clarify the problem: the data you're trying to clean has Spanish month names (e.g. "ene") but *no dot*, which would be required for parsing with strptime?

Comment: Exactly, my strings don't have the dot and the dot is necessary to clean it well. I have the same in ubuntu and it works fine because is not necessary the dot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make use of dateutil's parser, where you can set custom month names via the [parser.parserinfo](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html#dateutil.parser.parserinfo) class. Ex:

```
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'Spanish_Spain.1252') # set locale for reproducibility
```

```
import calendar
from dateutil import parser
    
# subclass parser.parserinfo and set custom month names with dots stripped:
class LocaleParserInfo(parser.parserinfo):
    MONTHS = [(ma.strip('.'), ml) for ma, ml in zip(calendar.month_abbr, calendar.month_name)][1:]
    
s = '18ene2021'
print(parser.parse(s, parserinfo=LocaleParserInfo()))
# 2021-01-18 00:00:00
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's a brilliant and elegant solution! The only problem is that you need to change each string.. Like I said, in ubuntu is not necessary this step and I thought that with a change in the regional settings of Windows10 or touching some setting in LOCALE, I could have the same like ubuntu

Comment: @GonzaloAB sure, addressing the "root" of the problem would be nicer, but this way, you should be able to make it work cross-platform. I had a similar issue on Windows vs. Linux for German locale - I think this falls back to OS-specific libraries. So I also ended up using a work-around.